# how to change "add to wish list" button with an image

Tags: magento2, wishlist, addtowishlist

How do I change this 'add to wish list' button into an icon? I have a png file for this button
[image]

I did some research online. Some people say by CSS, but not work for me

```
<style>
.product-social-links .action.towishlist:before {
    background-image: url('/wysiwyg/icons-like-customize-share-sized.png');
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.product-social-links .action.towishlist:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:   //as per icon size
    width:'';   //as per icon size
    background-image: url('/wysiwyg/icons-like-customize-share-sized.png');
}
</style>
```

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330865/57334

Answer (score 0):

Replace the anchor tag in ,

> app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

```
<a href="#"
   class="action towishlist notify-wishlist"
   data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>'
   data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><img src="<?=$block->getViewFileUrl('images/icons-like-customize-share-sized') ?>"/></span></a>
```

Add the icons-like-customize-share-sized.png in

> app/design/frontend/[your theme]/web/images

Comment: Can you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330865/57334